# SnapSVG Safari/Firefox Rotation Bug

Tags: css, firefox, svg, safari, snap.svg

I'm trying to animate the stroke of a circle to fill in over time. And I noticed that Safari didn't seem to be applying my transform: rotate via SnapSVG, but rotating via CSS works. IE9+ applies proper rotation. Firefox does it's own thing (backwards)

http://codepen.io/davechiu/pen/bEuar

The Blue and Red arcs should be the same (and rotating clockwise).

```js
var s1 = new Snap('#example1');
var s2 = new Snap('#example2');
var dialRadius = 120;
var dialCircumference = Math.PI * 2 * dialRadius;
var sliver = 0.1;

var circle1 = s1.circle(150, 150, dialRadius).attr({
  id: 'circle1',
  fill: 'none',
  stroke: '#900',
  transform: 'r90,150,150',
  strokeWidth: 30,
  strokeDasharray: dialCircumference + 1,
  strokeDashoffset: dialCircumference + 1
});

var circle2 = s2.circle(150, 150, dialRadius).attr({
  id: 'circle2',
  fill: 'none',
  stroke: '#009',
  strokeWidth: 30,
  strokeDasharray: dialCircumference + 1,
  strokeDashoffset: dialCircumference + 1
});

var strokeDashOffsetBegin = dialCircumference;
var strokeDashOffsetEnd = (dialCircumference * sliver) + 0;

Snap.animate(strokeDashOffsetBegin,strokeDashOffsetEnd, function( value ){ 
  Snap('#circle1').attr({ 'strokeDashoffset': value })
}, 500, function(){
  console.log('done');
});
Snap.animate(strokeDashOffsetBegin,strokeDashOffsetEnd, function( value ){ 
  Snap('#circle2').attr({ 'strokeDashoffset': value })
}, 500, function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 1em;
}
svg#example2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     id="example1"></svg>
  
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     id="example2"></svg>

<script src="http://snapsvg.io/assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
```

Chrome/MSIE Output, Red = SnapSVG Rotation, Blue = CSS Rotation
[image: Chrome Output, Red = SnapSVG Rotation, Blue = CSS Rotation]
Safari Output, Red = SnapSVG Rotation, Blue = CSS Rotation
[image: Safari Output, Red = SnapSVG Rotation, Blue = CSS Rotation]
Firefox Output, Red = SnapSVG Rotation, Blue = CSS Rotation
[image: Safari Output, Red = SnapSVG Rotation, Blue = CSS Rotation]

Has anyone else run into this? Search seems to reveal nothing. Is this the only solve at the moment?

Behavior seems to be consistent on Safari across OSX, iOS, etc...

**EDIT**: I've found that I can invert the Firefox output to get it to behave like the other browsers... not ideal but consistency across browsers is good.

in CSS:

```
svg#example2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg); /* move this up so moz takes targeted change */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1,-1); /* invert mozilla output */
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

in Snap.SVG JavaScript attribute:

```
var circle1 = s1.circle(150, 150, dialRadius).attr({
  id: 'circle1',
  fill: 'none',
  stroke: '#900',
  transform: 'r90,150,150' + (isMoz)?' s1,-1':'', // target mozilla as you wish
  strokeWidth: 30,
  strokeDasharray: dialCircumference + 1,
  strokeDashoffset: dialCircumference + 1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

U have tried with transform origin?

```
transform-origin: center center;
```